# Power BI Calculate sum of column 2 when column 1 = " ? "

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to create two measures that sum up the values of column 2 when column 2 equals column 1's parameters.

For example I have a column named Current/Reset and another column named Linear Ft. I want to sum up the values of Linear Ft where column 1 = "Current" and then again for "Reset."

I continue to get errors when I try and write the formula. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need explicit measures for this. It's the default behaviour of Power BI to sum up numbers (aka. *implicit measure*), and if you filter *Linear Ft.* by the (unique) values of *Current/Reset* you get your desired result.

[image]

However, if you still want to have separate measures for this, use CALCULATE()

```
Current Sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Linear Ft.]),
    'Table'[Current/Reset] = "Current"
)

Reset Sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Linear Ft.]),
    'Table'[Current/Reset] = "Reset"
)
```